# value of input text is value="on" when posting to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that renders a textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarName,new{ id="carNameId"})
```

and I am binding it to a Model

```
            public class Car 
    {
        public Car()
        {

        }

        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.LengthInvalid)]
        [DisplayName("Car Name")]
        public string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

when I post to my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Car car)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var _car = _vehicle.Verify(car);
    }

    return View(_car);
}
```

the value of the CarName in the car class is "on" instead of the value I entered for example 'Ford' or "GT" in the form

what is happening in the binding?

why??

Answer (score 0):

I had a 2 radio buttons on the page named 'carName' and this was causing the problem